# Selenium webdriver - Java with Webservices

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng, soapui, web-service

In our application we are using web-services and DB, is it possible to integrate Selenium webdriver with web-services (Soap UI)?

If two different frameworks are integrated, whether this is good?.

My expectation is: Have to validate or compare actual result with webservices or DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In our application we are using web-services and DB, is it possible to integrate Selenium webdriver with web-services (Soap UI)?

Since this is in Java, yes it is possible to interact with SoapUI using the test runner or by [importing SoapUI into Java](http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=22797&sid=e6dc0f93514c0cb0991e7767c5eb35a7) and running it as a background task.

> If two different frameworks are integrated, whether this is good?.

I don't think the issue you will have will be the different frameworks. I think the issue will be the fact that SoapUI has a horrible integration into being remotely controlled. It's cumbersome, difficult and overall a pain. [I would suggest just adding the web services into your Java project](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/) and building a harness for it that way you have absolute control easily over the web services.

> My expectation is: Have to validate or compare actual result with webservices or DB.

So where is the need for Selenium here? It sounds like you need to call a webservice, check the data against results in the database and have an assertion checking that they match. No need to use Selenium for that.